# Bars of background color without container divs

Tags: html, css

It's trivial to obtain a centered, max-width website with a single background color by styling up the `body` element like so:

```css
body {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

header {
  height: 100px; /* Might not be static */
  background-color: red;
}

#main {
  height: 300px; /* Might not be static */
  background-color: yellow;
}

footer {
  height: 200px; /* Might not be static */
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
</header>
<section id="main">
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
```

However, if you want the background color *for each section* of the page to extend infinitely on either side, things can quickly get non-semantic:

```css
header {
  height: 100px; /* Might not be static */
  background-color: red;
}

#main {
  height: 300px; /* Might not be static */
  background-color: yellow;
}

footer {
  height: 200px; /* Might not be static */
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px black dotted;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</header>
<section id="main">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</section>
<footer>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</footer>
```

Is there a good way to achieve the effect of the second example without adding a container div to every top-level block?  Even a CSS trick that generates such containers dynamically would be preferable.

Comment: Can you post the final layout you want to get, e.g. are the background bars meant to be expanded outside of the 500px centered containers?

Comment: The second snippet is an approximation of the final layout.  The question states that the goal is to have a maximum width for page content, with each top-level block's background extending infinitely to either side - without using containers.

Comment: Are the rows fixed height like in your examples?

Comment: Not necessarily.  The header is fixed, but the main section and footer are dynamic.

Comment: <body>
  <header>
  <center class="container">
  </center>
</header>
<section id="main">
  <center class="container">
  </center>
</section>
<footer>
  <center class="container">
  </center>
</footer>
 </body>

Comment: I think what you did in the 2nd example is already a nice solution with a good balance of html/css to meet your goals.

Comment: @Constantin, <center> has been deprecated for 20 years.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-CENTER

Comment: and i am still using it ;)

Comment: <meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">p{color:red;text-align:center;margin-left:25%;height:300px;width:50%;border:1px solid red;margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;padding:0;
} body{margin:0;text-align:center;height:100%;width:100%;max-width:100%;max-height:100%;}</style>
<p>yep</p><p>yep</p><p>yep</p>

Comment: @Brian Bauman lol i forgot backgrounds ! <meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">p{color:red;text-align:center;margin-left:25%;height:300px;width:50%;border:1px solid red;margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;padding:0;
} body{margin:0;text-align:center;height:100%;width:100%;max-width:100%;max-height:100%;}</style>
<p style="background-color: red;">yep</p><p style="background-color: yellow;">yep</p><p style="background-color: blue;">yep</p>

Answer (score 1):

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  /* Might not be static */
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#main {
  height: 300px;
  /* Might not be static */
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

footer {
  height: 200px;
  /* Might not be static */
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

footer,
header,
#main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 2px black dotted;
}

header:before,
#main:before,
footer:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100vw;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

header:before {
  background-color: red;
}

#main:before {
  background-color: yellow;
}

footer:before {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  My header so nice;
</header>
<section id="main">
  my content so nice
</section>
<footer>
  my footer very low
</footer>
```

Comment: Very clever!  This can be improved further by adding `background-color: inherit;` to the main `:before` selector, allowing the individual `:before` rules to be removed.

It's a pity the borders create gaps in the background, but my use case doesn't actually require borders.